# RegQueryValueEx does not get more than one REG_BINARY data

Tags: c++, windows-7, codeblocks

I have a key in the Registry which contains 3 `REG_BINARY` values.
I can read the first one perfectly, but when I try to get the second and third values, I get an `ERROR_MORE_DATA` error, even if the data is only 10 BYTES. I don't obtain the value but I get the good datalength of it.

```
HKEY hKey;
long nError;
DWORD sizeData;
BYTE Data[256];

nError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\MyProg\\Test01", 
NULL,KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey  );
if(!nError)
{ nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "1", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&Data, 
   &sizeData); // This one does OK

  nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "2", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&Data, 
   &sizeData); // Here I get the good value for sizeData but ERROR_MORE_DATA

  nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "3", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)Data, 
   &sizeData); // Same ERROR here too
}
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

NOTE: In the Registry I have those keys:

```
1    REG_BINARY    c5 31 56 f4 d3 22 17 88 64 e3
2    REG_BINARY    45 48 47 c5 d2 21 77
3    REG_BINARY    dd ef 45 2e fc 10
```

What am I doing wrong?

I removed the test for `nError` to reduce the size of the code, but in my program I get `nError = ERROR_MORE_DATA`.

Comment: The last parameter is `[in, out]`. On input, it indicates the size of the buffer; on output, it contains the size of the data actually written. Therefore, `sizeData` needs to be initialized before each call to the size of the buffer. It works the first time because `sizeData` is not initialized at all before the call - it contains some random garbage, likely a very large value.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx): "*If the buffer specified by `lpData` parameter is not large enough to hold the data, the function returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA` and stores the required buffer size in the variable pointed to by `lpcbData`*". That means the value you pass in `sizeData` is smaller than the size of the data being read.

Comment: Thanks ! you did my day !